# Infusing AdSense into Joomla Template using JQuery Masonry

Tags: joomla, adsense, jquery-masonry

I'm aware of the JoomlArt JA Wall template but it doesn't appear to meet our use case as we have the need to include tiles in the feed that are Adsense banners.  I've read up on JQuery Masonry and see that it uses the infinite scroll feature.

Is it possible to create a Joomla template using Masonry that also will take Adsense banners ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible, just make sure you add the class you choose for masonry to each element; depending on what kind of elements you want to align: modules? blog items? it should be fairly easy; if you want to apply masonry to items across the whole page, just make sure you don't enclose modules and blog items in their own div groups.

Comment: I am using a Custom HTML module for the Adsense script. Does the template take care of assigning the class to the correct module?